# Render Error texture size is smaller than my output size, what does that mean?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, error

When I render my scene, the render is a pixelated yellow image. Then it tells me that my texture size is smaller than my output size? I have not found any answers on how to take care of this problem. Here is a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Check the output settings. Looks like you try to render a huge image 38,400 px(!) and it consumes 36GB of memory

Comment: if you enter *1000%* for *Output Properties > Dimensions > %* and try to render this then exactly this error happens (standard res of 1920x1080 and EEVEE render). Cycles can render it

Comment: As @Blunder mentioned - set your resolution to 100% instead of 1000% percent.

Comment: it worked thanks you guys !